# Python virtualenv no module named django

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, centos, virtualenv

In my ec2 machine i need to run  a django project,
I do the below thinks:

Install python 3.4:

```
sudo yum install python34
```

ok, now i create a virtual enviroment for python 3:

```
virtualenv -p python3 .venv3
```

at this point activate my venv:

```
source .venv3/bin/activate
```

all done!
Now i have to install django:

```
pip install django
```

the installation was ok but when i try to check my django version:

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

system return the error "No module name django found"
How is possible?
In my machine there is also python 2.7 installed. 
I try outside the virtualenv to remove django with:

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall django
```

all done, but in my .venv3 enviroment the issue is still present.
How can i fix the problem?

i also tried to reinstall django like this:

```
 pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall django
```

response:

> Collecting django
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/0e/afdacb47503b805f3ed213fe732bff05254c8befaa034bbada580be8a0ac/Django-2.0.6-py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting pytz (from django)
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/83/15f7833b70d3e067ca91467ca245bae0f6fe56ddc7451aa0dc5606b120f2/pytz-2018.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Installing collected packages: pytz, django
>     Found existing installation: pytz 2018.4
>       Uninstalling pytz-2018.4:
>         Successfully uninstalled pytz-2018.4
>   Successfully installed django-2.0.6 pytz-2018.4

but when i try:

```
pip freeze
```

response is:

> gunicorn==19.8.1
>   pytz==2018.4
>   virtualenv==16.0.0

Why django isn't installed?

thanks in advance

Comment: With you venv activated: what does `python --version` and `django-admin --version` return?

Comment: Hi,python --version return Python 3.4.8,

Comment: django-admin --version return:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.venv3/bin/django-admin", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'"

Comment: What is the output if you run `which pip` before `pip install django`? Is it in the virtualenv?

Comment: ~/.venv3/bin/pip
~/.venv3/bin/pip
/usr/bin/install
/usr/bin/which: no django in (/home/ec2-user/.venv3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)

Comment: what's output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: gunicorn==19.8.1
pytz==2018.4
virtualenv==16.0.0

Comment: I had the same issue few time ago. I don't remember exactly How I solved this one, but try : `pip install Django==2.0.6` or `pip install django --user`

Comment: Do you still need help getting a Django application installed on AWS?  I would highly recommend using Elastic Beanstalk.  I followed the guide here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html last week with Django2.1 and Python 3.6 and it works great.  Elastic Beanstalk will help keep things simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on your version of python so you need to install pip3

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Then, you have to create a virtual environment with venv

`pip3 -p python3.6 virtualenv name`

After that install Django:

`pip3 install Django`

As in the recent version, you can use

`apt-get install python3-django`

Or you can simply  do the follwing:

`sudo apt-get install python3 virtualenvwrapper`

`mkvirtualenv <venv> -p python3`

`workon <venv>`

`--system-site-packages`

`pip install Django`